# Oracle SQL Developer load Java error

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I'm trying to load Java code to my Oracle SQL developer. On Load java, I choose Java source from my hdd (from `NetBeans` destination folder) and I get the below error. Any help?

[image: picture]

here is the code. It works well in NetBeans and I'm trying to load it in SQL Developer in .java file

```
package c2_01_signhelloworld;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.BouncyCastleDigest;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.DigestAlgorithms;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.ExternalDigest;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.ExternalSignature;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeSignature;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeSignature.CryptoStandard;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PrivateKeySignature;

public class C2_01_SignHelloWorld {

    public static final String KEYSTORE = "C:/Users/kranjcevicb/Documents/itext/2/ks";
    public static final char[] PASSWORD = "password".toCharArray();
    public static final String SRC = "C:/Users/kranjcevicb/Documents/itext/2/unsigned1.pdf";
    public static final String DEST = "C:/Users/kranjcevicb/Documents/itext/2/unsigned1_signed.pdf";

    public void sign(String src, String dest,
            Certificate[] chain,
            PrivateKey pk, String digestAlgorithm, String provider,
            CryptoStandard subfilter,
            String reason, String location)
                    throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, DocumentException {
        // Creating the reader and the stamper
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');
        // Creating the appearance
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
        appearance.setReason(reason);
        appearance.setLocation(location);
        appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36, 748, 144, 780), 1, "sig");
        // Creating the signature
        ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
        ExternalSignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, provider);
        MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, signature, chain, null, null, null, 0, subfilter);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, DocumentException {
        BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
        Security.addProvider(provider);
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(KEYSTORE), PASSWORD);
        String alias = (String)ks.aliases().nextElement();
        PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, PASSWORD);
        Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
        C2_01_SignHelloWorld app = new C2_01_SignHelloWorld();
        app.sign(SRC, String.format(DEST, 1), chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, provider.getName(), CryptoStandard.CMS, "Test 1", "Ghent");
        app.sign(SRC, String.format(DEST, 2), chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA512, provider.getName(), CryptoStandard.CMS, "Test 2", "Ghent");
        app.sign(SRC, String.format(DEST, 3), chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, provider.getName(), CryptoStandard.CADES, "Test 3", "Ghent");
        app.sign(SRC, String.format(DEST, 4), chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.RIPEMD160, provider.getName(), CryptoStandard.CADES, "Test 4", "Ghent");
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide code and error stacktrace in code format. It will help more than image. Always provide your efforts, It will help you more

Comment: if your code compiles in netbeans but does not in sqldeveloper then you might want to check the classpath that sqldeveloper sees when trying to compile the source. also the source and the compile error it self would be a great help to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem while loading the java class using the left pane java option in sqldeveloper. However when i tried loading the java using below code , it worked out

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "JavaClassName" AS
 public class JavaClassName{
     public static String MyFunction(){
      .....do something......
      return "output";
     }
  }
```